# Displaying a form as many times as the user wishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dom

I am trying to design a webpage to accept name rollnumber,department,number of courses,grade in each course etc and print the Grade card

My problem is- How should I display the form (accepting subject code,grade,number of credits) n number of times( where n is the number of courses)

Thank you

Comment: You can use inline grid editing where -> number of rows =number of courses.

Comment: You can generate a form in a javascript function with insertAdjacentHTML and call it N number of times. Of course your form name must change every time : like form1, form2...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `jQuery`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX Request Sample</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addForm(){
            $('div#formsDiv').append($('#sneakyDiv').html());
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="formsDiv">

    </div>
    <div id="sneakyDiv" style="display: none;">
        <form id="myForm">
             <input id="username" name="username">
        </form>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addForm();">ADD FORM</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        addForm();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```